# Brett has £135, Dustin has £70, Greg has £35.

Tags: divisibility

Brett gives some money to Dustin & Greg.
The ratio of the amount of money Brett, Dustin and Greg have now is 3:2:1
How much money did Brett give to Dustin?

I considered saying Brett gets 3 parts of £240 but thats obviously wrong because what do the others get?
So help please.

Comment: How much effort did you make in attempting to answer this question on your own?

Comment: quite abit, why? is it too easy or something?

Comment: No, that's not the point. When posting a question here, you're expected to show what you've tried.

Comment: ok i'll show you what i thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total amount of money is equal to $135+70+35=240$.

In the end, this total amount is distributed in the ratios $3:2:1$ which means that there are $3+2+1=6$ parts altogether.

So, in the end, Dustin has $\frac{2}{6}$ of this total $=\frac{2}{6}\times240=80$. Therefore Brett must have given Dustin $80-70=10$.

Comment: cool man,thanks. i get it 90% jus has to fully sink in

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Solve the following system of two equations in two variables:

- $\frac23(135-x-y)=70+x$
- $\frac13(135-x-y)=35+y$

Comment: Mate i do not know how to work out 2/3(135−x−y)=70+x. my intelligence is abysmal

Comment: @greg: Start by multiplying each side of the equation by $3$ (you can do the same with the other equation too BTW).

Answer (score 1):

Brett does get 3 parts of £240. How much is each part? How many parts are there in total?

Comment: awesome mate, someone else told me, but  thanks alot anyway.